# updating a column in table 1 by joining information from table 2

Tags: mysql, sql-server, toad

I have tabel 1 that has VIN which i want to update. 
table 1 and table 2 has OBJ ID and POID (respectively) which are same. 
I only know device ID which is present in table 2.

```
update table.1 set VIN = '5TDKK3DC6BS018229'
from table 2, table 1
where 2.device ID = 'TCAXLcKkt3'
and 2.OBJ = 1.POID;
```

I am getting SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: Are you running this query in SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: Also, it seems you want to update VIN with another column value in table2. Is that right?

Comment: @ Sunil I am using TOAD actually.
and yes, i am trying to add VIN in table one by corresponding value in table 2. 
Basically i know device ID in table 2. and i m updating VIN in table 1. the only thing which joins two things are OBJ in table 1 and POID in table 2.

Comment: So there is a column called `VIN` in table2. If yes, then check the query I have just posted.

Comment: I have added query assuming `table2.VIN` column exists.

Comment: Remove the semi-colon at end of your query and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you remove the semi-colon at end of the query since some databases will complain if its there in TOAD.

If you are using SQL Server then following query will work.

```
UPDATE table1
SET VIN = '5TDKK3DC6BS018229'
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.POID = table2.OBJ
WHERE table2.deviceID = 'TCAXLcKkt3'
```

If you want the same query for MySQL, then use the one below.

```
UPDATE table1 a 
       JOIN table2 b 
         ON a.poid = b.obj 
SET    a.vin = '5TDKK3DC6BS018229' 
WHERE  b.deviceid = 'TCAXLcKkt3'
```

If you are using Oracle, then use the query as below.

```
UPDATE table1 
SET    table1.vin = '5TDKK3DC6BS018229'
 where exists (SELECT table2.obj 
                     FROM   table2 
                     WHERE  table2.obj = table1.poid 
                            AND table2.deviceid = 'TCAXLcKkt3')
```

Comment: the 2nd query for MYSQL is giving me missing Set keyword error.

Comment: The second query is for MySQL, but it seems you want a query for Oracle. Let me create an Oracle query for you.

Comment: I have posted an Oracle version of the query. Please check it out.

Comment: i don't think that will work. table2 doesnt have vin.

Comment: Oh, I thought you said that in your comment under original post. So you want to update VIN to what value? What column in table2 will replace VIN?

Comment: table 1 has VIN which i want to update and table 1 also has OBJID.
table 2 has Device (which i know) and table 1 also has  POID.
OBJID = POID.

now based on that, I want to change VIN if i know just the Device ID.

Comment: So your VIN value is a static value and its `5TDKK3DC6BS018229`?

Comment: correct. I want the VIN to update to 5TDKK3DC6BS018229. I know the Device ID which is TCAXLcKkt3.

Comment: I have updated all three queries. Use the ORACLE version since it appears you are using ORACLE in Toad.

Comment: Thanks. it seemed to have worked. though. I didnt get any kind of message to show if it worked or not. not sure why. I did a select query to see if VIN was changed. it seemed to have worked.

Comment: Great. Toad will throw back an error if the query doesn't fire successfully. So that means it did fire successfully. I am not sure what settings you have in your Toad but the query has worked.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Sunil. I will try it once more later on in another VIN. and give you an update (incase you are interested). i appreciate your help buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Error message looks like you are using `Oracle`.

If am not wrong this is what you are looking for

```
UPDATE table1 
SET    vin = '5TDKK3DC6BS018229' 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   table2 B 
               WHERE  table1.obj = B.poid 
                      AND B."device id" = 'TCAXLcKkt3')
```

In Oracle to update table from another table using `Join` try the below syntax

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT A.VIN
 FROM table1 A
 INNER JOIN table2 B
 ON A.OBJ = B.POID
 WHERE B."device ID" = 'TCAXLcKkt3'
) t
SET T.VIN = '5TDKK3DC6BS018229'
```

Comment: gives me A.VIN is invalid identifier

Comment: sorry for slow message. I am updating the query as i go along.
I am getting B.device_ID is invalid identifier. for the 1st query you gave.